# Why the DLL generated from Java jar file doesn't show namespace

Tags: java, c#, ikvm

I need to use a java jar file in my c# (VS 2019) console application. OS is Windows 10.
I use **ikvm-7.2.4630.5** and the **dll** file is generated without error. I added reference to  **dll** and **KVM.Open.JDK.Core.dll** ,in **C#** application.
The issue happens when using  “**using** ” keyword to import the package. I get the error "*Type or namespace name cannot be found*".

I did the following steps:

1)I wrote a test code to see if I can make it work.

Simple java class file:

```
package Msg;

public class MyMessage {

    public static void WelcomMsg(String msg) {
        System.out.println("Welcom " + msg);
    }

    public static void GoodByMsg(String msg) {
        System.out.println("Good Bye " + msg);
    }

}
```

2)The jar (msg.jar) file created in JavaSE-1.7 environment (using eclipse )

3)I can run either of these commands without error to generate dll (in `folder ikvm-7.2.4630.5\\bin`):

```
ikvmc -target:library -out:msg.dll -recurse:”./\*.jar
```

or

```
ikvmc -target:library msg.jar
```

--message after dll is generated ---------------
IKVM.NET Compiler version 7.2.4630.5
Copyright (C) 2002-2012 Jeroen Frijters
http://www.ikvm.net/

msg.dll is generated.

4)Added reference to **msg.dll** and **IKVM.Open.JDK.Core.dll** in C# console project (VS 2019).

5)"using" directive (using Msg;) generating error: **Type or namespace name cannot be found**

Basically the dll file seems empty.
Any help will be appreciated.

thanks

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than on other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Comment: ikvm-7.2.4630.5 and JavaSE-1.7 are old versions, released more than 10 years ago. Is there any particular reason to use them instead of current versions? They are probably full of security vulnerabilities at this time.

Comment: I was directed to this version ikvm-7.2.4630.5 just by searching for solution. Most of the postings are old and I ended up to this old version. I will try the latest versions.